# How can I access the values inside of my recycler view?

Tags: android

I am trying to access the values inside of my `RecyclerView` and pass them to another item. I have a `onClick()` method which is called when the item is tapped and I can get it's position by using the `getPosition()` method.

```java
private List<BucketItem> mItemList;
private Context mContext;

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener
{
    public CheckedTextView nameCheckedTextView;
    public TextView descriptionBox, date, latitude, longitude;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        nameCheckedTextView = (CheckedTextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.checkedTextView);
        descriptionBox = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemDescription);
        date = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemDate);
        latitude = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemLatitude);
        longitude = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemLongitude);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, EditItem.class);
        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "position = " + getPosition(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Problem is that I don't know how to get the actual field values of the item so that I can pass it to the next activity. Does anyone know if there is a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can access to that "item" inside `onBindViewHolder()` (in the recyclerView adapter):

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.update(items.get(position));
}
```

and inside ViewHolder:

```
public void update(Item item) {
    // here you can use "item"
}
```

EDIT: you can have a `private Item item` inside the `ViewHolder`, and inside `update()` do:

```
public void update(Item item) {
    this.item = item;
}
```

Now you can use `this.item` inside `onClick()`

Comment: How does that help me if my onClick method is inside the ViewHolder?

Comment: It can't recognize `Item` also I don't understand at all what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Inside onBindViewHolder if you some data as final Strings or final ints and then create an onClickListener with these finals then every time the new onClickListerners will be called they will be called with the finals inside them.

this is a simplified version from my app:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(FR_Adapter.ViewHolder holder, final int positionCard) {

    //this is where you call the db and fill the card with data,
    CardView cardView = holder.cardView;
    TextView textView = (TextView) cardView.findViewById(R.id.question);
    final String stringInTextView = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    textView.setText(stringInTextView); // this example should only show the time when the card was created

    cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            reactToClick(positionCard,stringInTextView,true);
        }
    });
}

private void reactToClick(int positionCard,String stringInTextView, boolean wasClick) {
    Log.v("custom Log.v call","click at position " + positionCard + "text in card was" + stringInTextView);
}
```

(basically if you have 20 cards then each of the 20 onClickListener will remember the String you saved when the card was first shown + that int positionCard)

```
//to add more vars just 1create them as final, 2add them in the method call, 3modify the method to have more arguments:

final String newVariable = MainActivity.getAppStartTime() // << 1add this

reactToClick(positionCard,stringInTextView,true,newVariable); // << 2edit this

reactToClick(int positionCard,String stringInTextView, boolean wasClick, String newVariable) // << 3edit this
```

Comment: So if the card has more than just one string do I need to pass that information to the `reactToClick` method?

Comment: above is info @GabrielaMarinho